# regular expression in order to replace a string except in string literals

Tags: python, regex

We have a large code base in c++. We want to repalace the string „NULL“ with the string „nullptr“ in the entire code base using python. The problem is that the string „NULL“ also occurs in a lot of string literals and we do not want to replace those findings. Please help me to find a proper regular expression for this task.

Example 1 (without string literal):
input: int* a = NULL;
output: int* a = nullptr;

Example 2 (with string literal): 
input: std::string str = "NULL";
output: std::string str = "NULL";

Example 3 (without string literal): 
input: m_pGetFunction1(NULL);
output: m_pGetFunction1(nullptr);

Example 4 (with string literal): 
input: "SELECT * FROM tab1 WHERE val is NULL;"
output: "SELECT * FROM tab1 WHERE val is NULL;"

[At this webpage](http://wordaligned.org/articles/string-literals-and-regular-expressions) I found the regular expression in order to find string literals using the Python regular expression library. The regular expression reads:

`string_literal_pattern = r'"([^"\\]|\\.)*"'`

Comment: Providing some sample input cases has a better change of getting a quality answer.

Comment: Depending on the full scope of your problem (it's hard to give a solution with much confidence when you describe it as "a large codebase" but only give a couple of examples), you might just be able to search for `NULL;` (with a semi-solon) are replace it with `nullptr;`?

Comment: What are the allowed characters of what comes before the equals sign? Is this sufficient? `^(\S.*? = )NULL;`  https://regex101.com/r/xiRoRq/1

Comment: Or similarly, you could do a search+replace of `NULL --> nullptr` on all lines that **don't mention `string`**?

Comment: Or, maybe, you could use a lookahead/look-behind to ensure that `NULL` isn't proceeded/followed by a quotation mark?

Comment: Or, as a fourth solution, maybe you could search and replace `= NULL` --> `= nullptr`? Like I said, there are lots and lots of possible approaches.

Comment: Or exclude matching the single or double quote `^([^"'\r\n]*)\bNULL\b` https://regex101.com/r/jxH36W/1 or with the regex PyPi module `(["']).*?\1(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\bNULL\b` https://regex101.com/r/TJQ3P4/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
res = re.sub(r'(?<!")\bNULL\b(?!.*")', 'nullptr', inputstr)
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/7I1Ar4/4)

Comment: Thank you very mutch. But the problem is that NULL is replaced for example in the following string literal "SELECT * FROM tab1 WHERE val is NULL;". [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/7I1Ar4/3)

Comment: @BlueTune: This was not specified in your question. You should edit your question and add real test cases.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The proposal is implemented.

Comment: @BlueTune: See my edit.